# find and replace zeros with a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, replace, find, sum

Once again, sorry if this has been asked before and if its too specific but I'm very stuck and can't quite find a solution.

I have a matrix of say 3 members of a structure called 2, 4 and 16 (in column 1) that have values along their relative distance e.g. member 2 has values at the start, 0m, then at 0.5m then the end of its length 1.5m, where member 4 starts at 0m etc. So that my matrix looks like this:

```
2   0     125
2   0.5   25
2   1.5   365
4   0     25
4   0.6   57
16  0     354
16  0.2   95
16  0.8   2
```

and I want to create a matrix that has the overall distance along all the members 2, 4 and 16 combined:

```
2   0     125
2   0.5   25
2   1.5   365
4   1.5   25
4   2.1   57
16  2.1   354
16  2.3   95
16  3.1   2
```

is there any way to do this in matlab? Like possibly locating the first zero and adding the value above it to all the rest of the values below then find the next zero value and so on?

Please tell me if this isn't clear, I realise it's a bit confusing but not too sure how to explain it better!

Comment: it sounds like you are doing a cumulative sum, but its not very clear to me. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your algorithm. Can you specify what is the problem?

Comment: @Amro I don't think it's a cumulative sum. He has three consecutive sections (rowwise) in his matrix, and want to shift the data in the 2nd column of the 2nd to last section so that they all connect to eachother. Now the 2nd column is resetted to zero at each section start.

Comment: @aiuto: Is it possible that they are multiple zeros at the start of a member?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: ah I see, thanks for the explanation. So all we have to do is process each section by adding the last value of the previous section (using the updated result from the previous step)

Comment: that's what I think, but then there also is an error in aiuto's example (the 3.1 in his 2nd matrix should be 2.9) @aiuto: some feedback please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following:

```
idx = find(diff(M(:,1)));
v = zeros(size(M,1),1);
v(idx+1) = M(idx,2);
M(:,2) = M(:,2) + cumsum(v);
```

The result:

```
M =
            2            0          125
            2          0.5           25
            2          1.5          365
            4          1.5           25
            4          2.1           57
           16          2.1          354
           16          2.3           95
           16          2.9            2
```

Note the last value in the second column disagrees with what you described (`2.9` vs `3.1`). Either you had a typo, or I'm still not getting it...

Comment: Hi! thank you very much, yes sorry there was a typo it should have been 2.9! I cant believe how stuck i was on this thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [2   0     125;
        2   0.5   25;
        2   1.5   365;
        4   0     25;
        4   0.6   57;
        16  0     354;
        16  0.2   95;
        16  0.8   2];

idx0 = find(data(:,2)==0);
idx0 = idx0(2:end); %ignore first zero of first member, doesn't need an offset

offset = data(idx0-1,2);
N = size(data,1);
for ii=1:numel(idx0)
    idxs = 1:N>=idx0(ii);
    data(idxs,2) = data(idxs,2) + offset(ii);
end
```